# Accessing Entity Manager from Model Class in Silex

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, silex, entitymanager

I'm using Silex for simple site.
I use Doctrine DBAL and that project
https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider
as ORM and Entity Manager.
I know how access that manger from controller but I wonder how to do that from Model class.
For example we have

```
class UserModel {

public function getPhones() {

????????

}

}
```

I don't know how to access EntityManager from Model class to find User Phones.

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not.

Instead you should set up your entities so your user has a relation to its phones, something like this:

```
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Phone")
     */
    private $phones;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->phones = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

and the neccessary getters/setters. After this, you won't need the entity manager in your entity.